# What is a "ratchet drum"?

Tags: meaning, definition, word-meaning

From [here](http://www.billboard.com/articles/news/dance/7981780/snakehips-galantis-dances-sam-smith-too-good-at-goodbyes-remix):

> Chopped string samples and **ratchet drums** push this remix right to the dance floor.

A "ratchet drum key" is a tool used on certain drums. But I don't know what a "ratchet drum" is/looks like.

Comment: There's no such thing as a ratchet drum. The "drum" there is an attributive noun modifying "key." [A "drum key" is used to tune drums](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=isch&sa=1&ei=c4cTWvX_Eom4jwPYs4uICw&q=%22ratchet+drum+key%22&oq=%22ratchet+drum+key%22&gs_l=psy-ab.3..0i30k1.4029.4507.0.5137.4.4.0.0.0.0.135.379.0j3.3.0....0...1c.1.64.psy-ab..1.3.377...0j0i7i30k1.0.HkErUTJuZQo). Some  drum keys are of the ratchet variety, which means they work like a socket wrench, with a ratchet mechanism. All of which you could easily google, which is why I'm voting to close this question.

Comment: Well, I believe I have stated in the question that I know very well what "drum keys" are/are used for. The question is about a specific term in a specific context, which your comment doesn't really address. I think your comment just repeats what I already said in the question, and you are accusing me of being to lazy to Google...

Comment: It absolutely addresses that. You seem to be under the impression that there is such a thing as a "ratchet drum." You should read the first sentence of my comment again.

Comment: @Robusto: The question is about an actual use (in a credible source) of the exact phrase "ratchet drum" as though it were an independent and specific thing, so if you assert that such a thing does not exist, take it up with billboard.com. See the linked article, or just look at the part formatted as a quote. "Ratchet drum key" is a red herring, and not what the question is based on.

Comment: The simpler explanation is that the writer of that piece is simply uninformed and/or a poor writer. Probably both.

Comment: I think this question is not about learning English, since the meaning of the individual words is not in question, and the terms themselves should be searchable if valid. It would be better to ask this on a music SE site, since that is the specific context.

Comment: @Robusto It's a little more complicated than that. Happily I have a resident authority on the subject who provides the Answer I take credit for below.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

My son the percussionist (with eight years of collegiate study and a broad familiarity with most genres of music) tells me that *ratchet* is here employed as an adjective, not an attributive noun. He says (and his reading is confirmed by the dubious authority of [Urban Dictionary](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=ratchet&utm_source=search-action)), that *ratchet* here means *nasty*, with the same possible anti-negative sense.

Comment: 'Wretched', really?  I always thought 'ratchet' in this context was a "misshearing" of two words that we in Australia shorten to '[RS](https://acronyms.thefreedictionary.com/RS)'.

Comment: It's not a mishearing, but deliberate use of the homophone to imply the intended word without having to actually write it.

Comment: @mcalex I hold no brief for urban dictionary's etymologies!

Comment: @Nij understood, hence the quotes.  The point was that 'wretched' was not the word that i thought `ratchet` was the deliberately used homophone of.

Answer (score 6):

The author is not talking about any particular, physical drum. *Drum* can refer to the [*sound* of a drum](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/drum), not just a physical drum.

I think the author is describing the particular drums (drum beats/samples) found in the song in terms of the sound a ratchet makes. The word "ratchet" modifies "drums" in "ratchet drums". If you turn a ratchet quickly, it sounds somewhat like the snare beats in the song in rapid succession. You can start to hear it at about :42 in the song on YouTube here: [Sam Smith - Too Good At Goodbyes (Galantis Remix)](https://youtu.be/IKaMejA5J34?t=42s).
This rapid drum beat style is prolific in pop music.

Answer (score 1):

Drummer here.  "Ratchet drums" is drummer slang for a poorly sampled snare drum sound like you get in older midi synthesizers and electronic drum kits.    Some of them are so off, they sound like a ratchet wrench, instead of a proper snare.  Many artists deliberately use the older samples just for that sound because they think it's cool.    So in context of language learning, this is genre specific slang you probably won't come across anywhere else but in a music forum.